# Erro no layout, deslocando à esquerda quando tem quebra de linha

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho em uma parte de um site, uma seleção das horas. Estou tentando deixar somente do layout passado, e o pessoal achou um erro e não estou sabendo como arrumar isso.

Segue imagem de exemplo, se perceber irá notar que à partir da segunda linha as caixas estão deslocando para esquerda, muito pouco, mas estão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando bootstrap 3.0.0.

Segue o html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="viewHours">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="08:00" name="optHour" />08:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="08:30" name="optHour" />08:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="09:00" name="optHour" />09:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="09:30" name="optHour" />09:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="10:00" name="optHour" />10:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="10:30" name="optHour" />10:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="11:00" name="optHour" />11:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="11:30" name="optHour" />11:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="13:00" name="optHour" />13:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="13:30" name="optHour" />13:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="14:00" name="optHour" />14:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="14:30" name="optHour" />14:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="15:00" name="optHour" />15:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="15:30" name="optHour" />15:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="16:00" name="optHour" />16:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="16:30" name="optHour" />16:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="17:00" name="optHour" />17:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="17:30" name="optHour" />17:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="18:00" name="optHour" />18:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="18:30" name="optHour" />18:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="19:00" name="optHour" />19:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="19:30" name="optHour" />19:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="20:00" name="optHour" />20:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="20:30" name="optHour" />20:30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="21:00" name="optHour" />21:00</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" value="21:30" name="optHour" />21:30</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

E fiz uma única alteração no css para remover as bordas arredondadas, mas que já removi e não é isso que esta dando o erro:

```
#viewHours .btn-group>.btn {
    border-radius: 0
}
```

[**Segue exemplo no Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WaqUj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque `margin:0px` em sua classe:

```
#viewHours .btn-group>.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaqUj/2/)

Comment: Valew mesmo, a única coisa que eu não tinha testado, simples e objetivo...

Answer (score 0):

Tentei usando `<table>` aqui e funcionou:

http://jsfiddle.net/WaqUj/1/

O único porém é que a quantidade de itens por linha fica fixa.

Comment: Então, isso não me serve pois as horas são dinâmicas à partir de outras seleções. Mas ainda assim obrigado